# Angular save vars to laravel session with ajax call dont work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs, laravel-4

I want to save some var to my session, and when i make the request with ajax this dont work.
This is the service:

```
function HuntService( $http ) {
  this.hunts= {
    draws  : null,
    hunters: null
  };

  this.saveToSession = function( hunts) {
   var hunts = this.hunts;
    return $http.post('saveToSession', {
      hunts: hunts
    });
  };

}

HuntService.$inject = ['$http'];
module.exports = HuntService;
```

and the controller:

```
class HuntController extends \BaseController {

    public function saveItems() {
        Session::put('hunts', Input::get('hunts'));
        return Response::json(array('saved' => true), 200);
    }

    public function destroy($id) {
        Session::forget('hunts');
    }

     public function getHunts() {
        return Session::get('hunts') // dont exits
    }

}
```

And when im trying as test to get to this with regular request and no ajax its working.

Comment: What session driver are you using? `app/config/session.php`

Comment: im using the default file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

`var hunts = this.hunts;`

Here, `this.hunts` does not exist.

**NOTE:**

Use Inspect Element/Debug tool for inspecting the request & check whether it is sending any value for `hunts` attribute in post method or just blank. The laravel part looks ok.